# Netlify fails to deploy GatsbyJS project

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify

I haven't been using Netlify for a while, last time was june 2020 I believe, but now I wanted to update a previous project of mine. However I, when I attempt to delpoy the changes I pushed to github I get the error message:

```
6:37:55 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
6:37:55 PM:   "build.command" failed                                        
6:37:55 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
6:37:55 PM: ​
6:37:55 PM:   Error message
6:37:55 PM:   Command was killed with SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault): gatsby build
6:37:55 PM: ​
6:37:55 PM:   Error location
6:37:55 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
6:37:55 PM:   gatsby build
6:37:55 PM: ​
6:37:55 PM:   Resolved config
6:37:55 PM:   build:
6:37:55 PM:     base: /opt/build/repo
6:37:55 PM:     command: gatsby build
6:37:55 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
6:37:55 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/public
```

I googled quite a bit, and found some posts about using `CI= npm run build`, which I did attempt, I wasn't sure where I should insert the command so I attempted to insert it into the deploy settings and the package.json in my project, in which I got this error message:

```
6:27:10 PM:   Error message
6:27:10 PM:   Command failed with exit code 139: CI= npm run build
```

I've tried different variations of this, but I always end up with either of the two error codes. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what might be wrong?

Here is a link to a gist with both deploy dumps: https://gist.github.com/PotatoPope/ef00c5d3b53fdb860ce29112cfa1a92e

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to insert it into your package.json file, just set it as the build command in your build and deploy settings
[image]

Comment: Can you try deploying via Netlify CLI https://github.com/netlify/cli

Comment: This worked flawlessly, thank you. Do you have any idea what might've caused the bug?